# Ignore signals in csh on startup

Tags: linux, bash, shell, signals, csh

I'm still fairly new to Linux, but I'm even newer to the notions of SSH and PUTTY.  After I SSH into a linux box, I fire off the following command:

```
csh -c 'cd /; set echo off; set term=dumb; set echo on; pwd; csh -i'
```

This is all well and good except for the headaches caused by signal interrupts, such as Ctrl+C. I did research and came to the following conclusions:

1. In csh, `onintr -` can be used to block signals in a given script. This got me thinking about putting `onintr -` into the cshrc file: That way it would be executed each time I run the above command. But that line is only local to one script, so it wouldn't have any real global effect like I wanted.
2. I found that bash, unlike csh, has the trap command - a non-script-specific command that will redefine how certain signals are handled during the entire shell session.   command.  So I tried launching bash instead and modifying the code to fit. Looking at the bash man pages, I interpreted that `bash -c` behaves in much of the same way as `csh -c` so to replicate the above command, I tried to replace `csh` with `bash` and append `trap "" 2` to the command.

Therefore, the full command would be:

```
bash -c' cd /; set echo off; set term=dumb; set echo on; pwd; bash -i; trap "" 2'
```

But `bash -c` does not necessarily behave like `csh -c`, at least in this instance.

---

I'm at odds about how to go about resolving this issue. *How can I have the shell ignore Ctrl+C by default?*  Should I put `onintr -` into cshrc? Or would I be better off using bash and running the trap command? How should I go about implementing the better solution?

Comment: the onintr and trap early, otherwise it will do nothing (you write it just before your ssh closes)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Specifically, we're using PLINK to create the SSH session; it is the ultimate handler of the interrupt itself. Could you be a tad more specific as to where this can be establish and/or give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't fully see why you would use a statement such as

> bash -c ' cd /; set echo off; set term=dumb; set echo on; pwd; bash -i;'

You could just place `trap` before the `bash -i`, as to keep `bash -i` from receiving the signal, like in the following:

> bash -c ' cd /; set echo off; set term=dumb; set echo on; pwd; trap "" 2; bash -i;'